# Canvas App Choices - Combo Box- Dataverse

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, dynamics-365, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to create a data source with all available values of a picklist and bind to a combo box.  Don't want to query the data to get the available values but to get the metadata of the picklist to populate the combo box.
Ex: populate all prioritycode of the case entity in the canvas app.

Comment: Can't you just add the field?